# Unable To Display The Output In The Border Using Functions In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table-2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div onload="myFunction()"></div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var num = 2;
            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                document.write(num + " * " + i + " = " + num * i);
                document.write('<br>');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm Trying To Style My 2 Multiplication Table Using Functions..Why I'm Unable To Display My Output In The Border..!I Required the solution please!!!

Answer (score 0):

A `div` does not get loaded, that is why the javascript is not executed.

However, the `body` does get loaded. Use this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table-2</title>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var num = 2;
            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                document.write(num + " * " + i + " = " + num * i);
                document.write('<br>');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, This Worked But When i'm trying to give styling for the body, it is not working sir, My main aim is to style that table with a border

Comment: In this case, you will have to create a `<div>`, style it with CSS, and write your data inside this `div`.